# unexpected '<=' in IF statement R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function which depending of the value of x, returns one of two functions. When I creating the following function, I get an error and I have no idea why.

```
t <- c(0.1,0.9,1.5)

squeze <- function(x){
 if(t[1]<x<=t[2]){
  exp(a1*x+b1)
 } else {
  exp(a2*x+b2)
 }
}
```

The error message:

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in:
"squeze <- function(x){
if(t[1]<x<="
> exp(a1*x+b1)
Error: object 'x' not found
> } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> exp(a2*x+b2)
Error: object 'x' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I would highly appreciate if someone was able to point out what I have missed.

In advance, thank you!

Comment: Each inequality is a test, and returns T or F. To combine 2 tests, you have to use `&` or `|`. So you can do `t[1] < x & x <= t[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser doesn't like it, that's why you get an error.

And it's a good thing because it may have got you in trouble, see:

```
(1 < 3) < 2 # TRUE
```

`1 < 3` is `TRUE` then `TRUE` is coerced to `1`, and `1<2` is `TRUE`

In R `>` is a function

```
`>` # function (e1, e2)  .Primitive(">")    
`>`(1,2) # FALSE
```

In this light you'll see why what you tried doesn't make sense in R.

Instead use `if(t[1] < x & x <= t[2])`

If you exclude both bounds you can use `data.table::between` :

```
between(x, t[1], t[2],F)
```

If you include both bounds you can use `data.table::between` or `dplyr::between` :

```
between(x, t[1], t[2])
```

`data.table` also permits syntax `x %between% c(t[1], t[2])`

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer @Moody_mudskipper!
It was in someway the same Gregor wrote but this answer is a little more detailed and explanatory.